# How to get the current session keys used by an active validator?

Tags: polkadot-js, session

There are `api.query.session.nextKeys` and `api.query.session.queuedKeys` for obtaining the next session keys for a validator ([doc](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage/#nextkeysaccountid32-optionkitchensinkruntimesessionkeys)).

But how do I query the current the session keys used by an active validator?

Answer (score 0):

You can query the AccountId's of the validators from the session pallet, and the AuthorityId's from their respective pallet's `fn authorities()` (eg: `Aura::authorities()`).
Then you can zip them up if you like.
The AccountIds and the keys are communicated to the pallets and stored in the pallets in order.